# bindFromRequest() not working in play framework 2.0. Form values are always null

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0

The problem is that, I can not read values in submitted form in play framework 2.0.  The value is always null,

Here is my code:

#### my model file

```
 package model;

 public class Paper {
    public String query;
 }
```

#### my index.scala.html

```
@(myform: Form[model.Paper])

@helper.form(action =routes.Application.newPaper()) {
   myvalue:  @helper.inputText(myform("query"))  <br><br>
   <br><input type="submit">
}
```

#### conf/routes

```
 POST     /newkey                  controllers.Application.newPaper()
 GET     /                           controllers.Application.index()
```

#### my Application.java

```
  public static Result index() {
    Paper paper = new Paper();
    paper.query = "initial value";
    Form<Paper> paperForm =  Form.form(Paper.class).fill(paper);
    return ok(index.render(paperForm);
  }

  public static Result newPaper() {
    Form<Paper> paperForm = Form.form(Paper.class).bindFromRequest();
    if (!paperForm.hasErrors()) {
        Paper paper = paperForm.get();
        Logger.info("query= " + paper.query); //why I always get "query= null" ???
    }
    return redirect(routes.Application.index()); 
 }
```

When I visit the html page, I can not see "initial value" in the text inputbox. When I fill the inputbox and click submit button, The printed log is always: `query= null`

I also monitored using chrome devtool. I saw post http request was sent. But the finial status code is 303, instead of 200.

If I use DynamicForm to process the submitted form in newPaper(), then I can read the query value as expected. But Why current code does not work?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify method attribute as well in form tag with value post. But helper method doesn't support method attribute. So do it this way.

```
@(myform: Form[model.Paper])

<form method="POST" action ="@routes.Application.newPaper()"> 
   query:  @helper.inputText(myform("query"))  <br><br>
   <br><input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: `method` attribute is determined by the `route` used in `action` attr, no need for manual using it.

Comment: It would be better if you check it in network tab of debug tools for method it is calling. I also had same issue earlier and by default it was making call with GET method.

Comment: I monitored the http request and confirmed it is sending POST request.  But the finial status code is 303. Not sure why status code is not 200?

Comment: instead of reverse routing try by specifying value "/newkey" in action attribute, if that again gives 303. Then try this API with Some rest client like POSTMAN. Kindly let me know the result, may be i can help you further.

Answer (score 0):

I have used `formFactory` instead of `Forms`.

Add `.withDirectFieldAccess(true);` in `myApplication.java` for `bindFormRequest`.

So your code should be:

```
Form<Paper> paperForm = Form.form(Paper.class).bindFromRequest().withDirectFieldAccess(true);
```

Instead of:

```
Form<Paper> paperForm = Form.form(Paper.class).bindFromRequest();
```

By this you can get all the fields.
You can find more help on this link - 
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/JavaForms

Answer (score 0):

I had encountered this problem even in 2022.

I am using version 2.8.x, and here are the solutions I had found.

#### Case 1.

If you have written *setters* in your model, the fields with *setters* will be filled automatically, and you should not have any problem.

#### Case 2.

If you don't have *setters* in your model, you should use the following line: `Form.form(Paper.class).withDirectFieldAccess(true).bindFromRequest(reqeust);`

The position where you put `withDirectFieldAccess(true)` matters in version 2.8.x, and you also have to pass the `request` object as the argument.